# Como direcionar cada usuario para sua pagina correspondente ao seu perfil de acesso usando asp.net identity com roles

Tags: asp.net, autenticação, asp.net-identity

Tenho 3 perfil cadastrados no banco SQL Server, são eles Master, Admin e User , quando fizer o login como faria para que cada usuário fosse direcionado para a sua view de permissão. por padrao a a rota ta carregando a home/index.

---

```
      // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        // Isso não conta falhas de login em relação ao bloqueio de conta
        // Para permitir que falhas de senha acionem o bloqueio da conta, altere para shouldLockout: true
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Tentativa de login inválida.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }
```

como implementaria o if, tentei e nao compilou, com a sua informação acima. @gilberto-b-terra-jr

Answer (score 0):

Redirecionar verificando a Role do usuário no método de login no AccountController?

**UPDATED**

```
switch (result) 
{
    case SignInStatus.Success:
        if (User.IsInRole("Master"))
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Master");

        if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

    case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
        return View("Lockout");
    case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
        return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
    case SignInStatus.Failure:
    default:
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Tentativa de login inválida.");
        return View(model);
}
```

Olá amigo, esse é um exemplo simples, veja se consegue aí, avisa a gente se ainda não conseguir!
Veja que coloquei uns **if (User.IsRole(** para redirecionar cada perfil de usuário para páginas (controllers/actions) diferentes!

Comment: A minha AccountController esta assim.

Comment: @MarlonAndrade eu alterei o código acima com um exemplo muito simples,  caso tenha dúvida avise onde enroscou aí.

Lembre-se que é mais importante você realmente compreender o código, cuidado com receitas de bolo.

:)

Comment: ok, aviso sim..estou quase terminando..@Gilberto B. Terra Jr.